# change container view content at runtime ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, storyboard

I have a container view which needs to load three table views. contents need to be switched at runtime by clicking a row cell in a table view.

I have searched solutions on stackoverflow, most of them are suggesting that have tab/button in the bottom to swap between, but that is not my case.Since one container view can only embed one tableview, and it is not able to change to another one at runtime.

Any suggestions?

Comment: make the number of controllers you need and call inside the container view on runtime based on the value called with [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"youridentifiername"];

Comment: **it is not able to change to another one at runtime** From where you get that information ?

Comment: Everything will be created initially just loading has to be done on clicking row cell in a table view.

Comment: make 3 tableview in seperate view controllers and call inside your current viewcontrollers containerview based on the cell tap change identifier name

 [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"youridentifiername"];

ie : 
if cell.rowindexpath == 1
 [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"youridentifiername1"];

if cell.rowindexpath == 2
 [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"youridentifiername1"];

if cell.rowindexpath == 3
 [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"youridentifiername1"];

etc...

Comment: The problem is how to add the desired table view into the container view. I have used "self.storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("services")" This line does not initialise the table view in that controller. but the tableview is not initialsed which is nil. Normally need to call "self.navigationController?.pushViewController(testView, animated: true)" to initialise the tableview inside. But i am not pushing just need it in my container view